# Firebase admin Cloud messaging Analytics label not appearing in the reports tab

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notifications to the app users using the firebase  cloud messaging service.The notifications are being sent successfully but the analytics label is not getting added under the Reports tab
Here is my admin nodejs script

```
admin.database().ref('chat/qa/branches/1510/lasid/1510/threads/fcmCampaign/fcmBody/')
    .once('value', (snapshot) => {
        let val = snapshot.val();
        if(val){

            if(val.title)
                payload.notification.title = val.title;
            if(val.body)                
                payload.notification.body = val.body;
            if(val.image)
                payload.notification.image = val.image;

            if(val.nTitle)
                payload.data.nTitle = val.nTitle;
            if(val.nMessage1)
                payload.data.nMessage1 = val.nMessage1;
            if(val.label)
                payload.fcmOptions.analyticsLabel = val.label;
            if(val.showNotifications)
                payload.data.showNotifications = val.showNotifications;  

                admin.database().ref('chat/qa/branches/1510/lasid/1510/threads/fcmCampaign/fcmToken/')
                .once('value', (snapshot) => {
                    var val = snapshot.val();
                  
                    if(!val){
                      res.send('something went wrong');
                      return
                    }
                    fcmList = [];
                    console.log('fcm_tokens val'+JSON.stringify(val));
                    let keys = Object.keys(val);
                        //NEW - block changes
                        for(let i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
                            fcmList.push(val[keys[i]]);
                            if((i+1) % breakPoint == 0){
                                sendMessageToDevices(fcmList);
                                fcmList = [];
                            }
                            if(i == keys.length-1 && fcmList.length!=0){
                                sendMessageToDevices(fcmList);
                                fcmList = [];
                            }
                        }
            });
        }
    });

function sendMessageToDevices(fcm_tokens) {
    console.log('fcm_tokens' + JSON.stringify(fcm_tokens));
    //admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcm_tokens,payload,options)
    payload.tokens = fcm_tokens;
    console.log('payload data ',JSON.stringify(payload));
    admin.messaging().sendMulticast(payload)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Successfully sent message : ' + JSON.stringify(response));
            res.status(200).send('Notification send successfully')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error sending message : '+error);
                res.status(400).send('something went wrong')
            })
})
```

The payload has fcmOptions.analyticLabel but still the label is not getting added under reports Tab and so not able to track the messages.If anybody could give some insight it would be great .Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was nothing wrong with the code.Firebase sometimes takes more than 24 hours to process the analytics.It took 48 hours in my case.